# Connection Pool shutdown on JVM Out.of.Memory exception

Tags: httpclient, connection-pooling, apache-httpcomponents

I'm observing "Connection pool shut down" exception in httpclient after once I receive Out.Of.Memory error in JVM.

I'm using aws-java-sdk-s3 v1.11.547 awsClient with httpclient 4.5.8. Any calls to awsClient (getObject) fail after JVM throws Out.of.Memory exception.

The following commit https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/commit/ca98ad69adad79de57d8b944ba524f7267a795cb seems to be the reason. It shuts down the connection pool on an Error instead of closing the connection.

Calls to awsClient continue to fail even after the process recovers from the exception.

Is this a bug in httpclient v4.5.7 henceforth? Also, Out.Of.Memory was received while executing a different code path i.e. other than the call to awsClient so does this mean that the connection manager was shared across class instances?

Comment: No, it is not a bug. It is fully intentional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deprecating it to v4.5.6 works for now. Allowing for connection leaks instead of the fix as per the commit (shared in the question) which shutsdown the